# Custom autocomplete flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete

[image: sample]

Is there any flutter package that can achieve something like this. I needed to have a searchable list like an autocomplete form and also returns the selected item as a string when tapped. I have not been able to find anything close to this yet.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead check this once

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/implementing-auto-complete-search-list-a8dd192bd5f6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is what you looking for

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) (
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: SubstringHighlight(
        text: dropDownItem,     // search result string from database or something
        term: searchTerm,       // user typed "et"
      ),
    );
  )
```

https://pub.dev/packages/substring_highlight

[image]